# Twig templates, inheritances and block usage

Tags: php, twig

I've created three templates using Twig. The first one has block `A` defined in it, the second one extends from the first one, but includes a third template which sets the content of block `A`.

When loading, through the browser, the url which renders b.html.twig, the content in block `A` (defined by the 3th template) is not positioned block _A is defined.

Example:

```
<!-- base.html.twig -->
{% block _css '' %}

{% block _header '' %}
{% block _content '' %}
{% block _footer '' %}

{% block _js '' %}


<!-- layout.html.twig -->
<!-- header and footer are placed in the raight zone -->
{% extends ::base.html.twig %}

{% block _header %}
    {% render "MyBundleBundle:Header:header"  %}
{% endblock %}

{% block _footer %}
    {% render "MyBundleBundle:Footer:footer" %}
{% endblock %}


<!-- my_template.html.twig -->
<!-- content is also placed in the right zone but css and js blocks in the included     template are not placed where declared in base.html.twig -->
{% extends MyBundleBundle::layout.html.twig %}
{% block _content %}
     SOME_CONTENT
     {% include MyBundleBundle::my_included_template.html.twig %}
{% endblock %}


<!-- my_included_template.html.twig -->
{% block _css %}
 <link.......................>
{% endblock %}

{% block _js %}
 <script..................>
{% endblock %}

MORE CONTENT BELONGING TO THE INCLUDED TEMPLATE
```

What i expect here is, _css blocks content to appear on top of the page and _js block content at the bottom, but that's not happening. I hope you can see where i'm going wrong, thanks!

Comment: I have edited your question a bit, could you please check if it is what you mean? And could you please check your sentences the next time, it was one big sentence which wasn't very understandable...

Comment: @Touki {% block _css '' %} is actually perfectly valid syntax. It's a shortcut for blocks with little content.

Comment: @lifo Can't find this on the doc but I guess I'm just learning every day.

Comment: @Touki http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html#block-shortcuts You can use literal strings or other dynamic variables. It's very handy sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

The [include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) tag does not work the way you think/hope it does. It simply includes the file into the current context. Which means you can't reference [blocks](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/block.html). You can only reference blocks in a template that has the [extends](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html) tag at the top of the file.

You're going to have to restructure the way you've designed your template to make this work for you. Instead of including `my_included_template.html.twig` you should possibly just render that template directly in your controller. That way it'll have full access to any inherited blocks.